# PSU with 2 ide power supply

Tags: hard-drive, power-supply

I have PSU with 2 IDE and 4 SATA power connectors and I have 1 IDE hdd and 1 ide dvd drive.
Can I hookup hdd and dvd drive onto those connectors?

P.S. I tried that and whenever dvd led lights up, so does hdd led.

Comment: Can you post a picture. You should be able to connect them up.

Comment: I'm sorry, what picture?  It just seems that power supply's ide connectors are on the same wire (and also with floppy drive) and cd enclosure is too far from hdd enclosure.  So I pulled cd out and placed it on top of open chassis closer to hdd for right now.  I've heard you can connect cd and hdd onto ide wire from mobo, but what aboyt psu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They should connect just fine, since it's just the power supply. On a side note, it's not uncommon for both indicator LED's to be lit at the same time, they don't mutually exclude one another.

Comment: I got it working!  hurray.  It is just cd and hdd were connected to different ide slots on the mobo.  I made cd a master and hdd a slave and it worked. Thanks to all.

Comment: Now I need to put cd back to its internal enclosure.  I hope there exist ide cables with greater distance btw units, so I can hook hdd and cd in a more cultural way.